# Making cURL GET call is C# and .Net

Tags: c#, .net, rest, curl

I've never used cURL in the past.  I am pretty proficient with c# and .net as well as javascript/jquery but I am trying to use the below cURL call and turn it into an HttpClient request through c# and MVC and just parse through the results and display them styled on a page.  There will never be a time that I upload or POST anything to the API, only retrieve active data and parse it on the web side.

the call is;

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H 'x-mjf-organization-id: 9'
-H 'x-mjf-api-key: 00000-9999-22222-2222-222'
https://test-site.info.com//v1/info
```

Based on the provided organization-id and api-keys from the 3rd party host, all of the data i receive will be independent to my organization.  I'm really unsure where to even begin, i've been digging through a lot of other posts regarding cURL but most are for uploading and posting data rather than just retrieving and parsing.  Any good references for me to begin with would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: This [converter](https://curl.olsh.me/) looks interesting/useful.

Comment: @SamAxe I will give that a try thank you for the quick suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This should be more or less equivalent to:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "");
//this header doesn't really make sense for a GET request...
//request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("x-mjf-organziation-id", "9");
request.Headers.Add("x-mjf-api-key", "...");

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

If the `-k` is really necessary, you can either set up global certificate handling that ignores all certificate errors like this

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, chain, err) => true;
```

*Note:* You should only do this for testing purposes and not in production.

If you only want to disable certificate checking for this `HttpClient` you can configure that by creating it with a configured `HttpClientHandler`:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, err) => true;
using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
[...]
```